# How do you turn refocusing on click in MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I'm new to vim and MacVim, and there is some setting that I can't figure out how to turn off.  What happens is I will click on a line and the screen will shift to make it be the line in the middle of my screen.  I know I shouldn't be clicking in vim, but this is really annoying.

I installed MacVim via `brew install macvim`.

Is there a command like `:set norefocus` or a plugin that might be doing this?

Comment: From what you are saying I assume that you are using a `.vimrc` that you didn't built yourself, you really shouldn't it will slower your learning of Vim more than creating it line by line. Still you might be interested in this question [how to debug my vimrc?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Comment: @statox thanks for the insight.  It was coming from my `.vimrc`.  The offending line was `set scrolloff=10000`. I've since removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending line, `set scrolloff=10000` was buried in my `.vimrc` which centers the cursor in the screen vertically. Removing it resolved my problem.

The [post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) @statox was very helpful for figuring out where the problem was coming from.